# Bash Script to Automate Telnet

Tags: bash, telnet

I'm trying to automate telnet, using this command which works great

```
echo -e "\x1dclose\x0d" |
  telnet abc.gc.ca 100 |
  grep Connected>/dev/null && printf "PASSED\n" || printf "FAILED\n"
```

But if I put it in a script, it just hangs and I have no idea why.

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERS=(
   "abc.gc.ca 100"
   "defg.gc.ca 101"
   "123.gc.ca 102"
   "xyz.gc.ca 103"
)

for host in ${SERVERS[@]}; do
  echo -e "\x1dclose\x0d" |
    telnet $host |
    grep Connected > /dev/null && printf "PASSED\n" || printf "FAILED\n"
done
```

Comment: Look into `expect`

Comment: `for host in ${SERVERS[@]}` doesn't do what you expect. It's *exactly identical to* `for host in ${SERVERS[*]}` until you add quotes around the expansion, so it's treating the port numbers as additional hostnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem was with the array dereference: Using `${SERVERS[@]}` without quotes around it was treating the port as a separate hostname.

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=(
   abc.gc.ca:100
   defg.gc.ca:101
   123.gc.ca:102
   xyz.gc.ca:103
)

for host_port in "${servers[@]}"; do
  host=${host_port%:*}   # put everything before the last : into host
  port=${host_port##*:}  # put everything after the last : into port
  if printf '\x1dclose\x0d' | telnet "$host" "$port" | grep -q Connected; then
    printf "PASSED\n"
  else
    printf "FAILED\n"
  fi
done
```

Other notes:

- All-caps variable names are used for names meaningful to the shell or operating system; other names are reserved for use by applications (like your script!), so you should use lowercase names where possible.
- `foo && bar || baz` is **not** identical to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`. For reliable code, use `if` -- not a short-circuiting ternary -- when you want the behavior of `if`.
- Using `grep -q` causes `grep` not to emit any output, so you don't need to redirect that output.
- `echo -e` is not reliable: even if the shell is 100% certain to be bash, if the shell is compiled or configured at runtime to provide an XPG-compatible `echo` (configuration that can be done through environment variables), `echo -e` may print `-e` on output instead of treating it as an argument.

All that said, consider using a dedicated port-scanning tool if this is intended for any kind of real-world use case. Such tools (nmap &c) can scan a large number of hosts in parallel without needing to run a subprocess for each, much less several subprocesses as used here.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `/dev/tcp' file.

```
SERVERS=(
   "abc.gc.ca/100"
   "defg.gc.ca/101"
   "123.gc.ca/102"
   "xyz.gc.ca/103"
)

for host in ${SERVERS[@]}; do
     timeout 3 bash -c "cat < /dev/null > /dev/tcp/$host" &&
         echo "PASSED" || echo "FAILED"
done
```